# Should I use cron.hourly or crontab?

Tags: linux, cron, awstats

It seems that all the suggestions for using/scheduling awstats is via crontab, as such:
`0 * * * * /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=mysite -update >/dev/null` (running awstats hourly).

However, if I check `crontab -l`, it says crontab is empty for my user.

However, when I check the `/etc/cron.hourly`, I've got an awstats file with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/share/awstats/tools/awstats_updateall.pl now         -configdir="/etc/awstats"           -awstatsprog="/usr/share/awstats/wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl" >/dev/null
exit 0
```

Just to let you know, my awstats is updated fine, it creates its reports, and all is good.

Does running a crontab command create an entry in the specified cron folder? (ie cron.hourly or cron.daily, etc) ? Or are they unrelated? If they are related, why is my user without a crontab entry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`crontab -e` is the traditional way to create a crontab. I find it to be awkward and old-fashioned, but people still use it.

`/etc/cron.hourly`, including `cron.daily`, `cron.weekly` & `/etc/cron.d`, etc. are provided by most Linux distros because they are convenient and work well with automation tools like package-managers and configuration management systems. It's very easy for a package manager to drop a file into `/etc/cron.hourly/foo` compared to scripting an edit an existing crontab. Editing a file programmatically through a package manager might corrupt the file, add duplicate entries, delete the wrong line, screw up comments, etc. See [Editfiles Considered Harmful](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-cfengine/2003-12/msg00019.html) for some discussion, as this problem has been around for a while.

> Does running a crontab command create an entry in the specified cron folder?

No. `/etc/cron.daily/foo` is created by the package manager, or created by hand. It is not created when you run the crontab command. `crontab -e` will create the crontab under `/var`, such as `/var/spool/cron/root`.

I prefer `/etc/cron.$period/foo` and `/etc/cron.d` because that hierarchy is neat and organized, and it's easy to script for my Configuration Management system. `/etc/crontab` is also available on Linux, but it's a bit monolithic and hard to edit programmatically. Systems like FreeBSD support `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/periodic`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I prefer it as well, as I'm used to dropping config files in .d folders (ie conf.d, etc)!

Comment: I can only agree on this. I also prefer to use the system's `/etc/crontab` when it's about running system taks instead of using root's crontab. This way, one can easily know what the system is up to without digging in each user's crontab.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Maybe mention some other differences: /etc/cron.$period/ contain self-sufficient scripts that are run by user root. OTOH /etc/cron.d/ contains include files in `crontab -e` format. Finally, /etc/cron* is intended to root-run scripts, while `crontab -e` is available to all users.

Comment: The `crontab -e` command is awkward by default.  So I created a script called `cte` which does two commands:  `export EDITOR=gedit` and then `crontab -e` so the editor is easier to work with.